# Recode Identifier for Different Combinations

Tags: r, combinations, rename, recode

I have a table in the following style:

```
Group Combi Value
----  ----  ----
x     A     1
x     A     2
x     B     1
x     B     3
x     C     2
x     C     3
y     D     1
y     D     2
y     E     1
y     E     3
y     F     2
y     F     3
```

I want to add another variable which renames the values in the "Combi" column in the following way: If I have the above table and "Combi" is e.g. A as in the first two rows, I want to change A to x_1_2 since both rows refer to "Group" x and the corresponding "Values" are "1" and "2" (note that a "Combi" is always assigned to exactly one "Group"). Thus, the table should look like this:

```
Group Combi Value Combi2
----  ----  ----  ----
x     A     1     x_1_2
x     A     2     x_1_2
x     B     1     x_1_3
x     B     3     x_1_3
x     C     2     x_2_3
x     C     3     x_2_3
y     D     1     y_1_2
y     D     2     y_1_2
y     E     1     y_1_3
y     E     3     y_1_3
y     F     2     y_2_3
y     F     3     y_2_3
```

Note that I always to sort the "Values" in a ascending order. Thus, I e.g. take y_2_3 and not y_3_2. Also note that I might have more than two entries per "Group" per "Combi". I would appreciate any help how to do this in R!

Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works using `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr);
df %>%
    group_by(Group, Combi) %>%
    arrange(Group, Combi, Value) %>%
    mutate(Combi2 = paste(Group, paste0(Value, collapse = "_"), sep = "_"))

# A tibble: 14 x 4
# Groups:   Group, Combi [6]
#   Group Combi Value Combi2
#   <fct> <fct> <int> <chr>
# 1 x     A         1 x_1_2_3_4
# 2 x     A         2 x_1_2_3_4
# 3 x     A         3 x_1_2_3_4
# 4 x     A         4 x_1_2_3_4
# 5 x     B         1 x_1_3
# 6 x     B         3 x_1_3
# 7 x     C         2 x_2_3
# 8 x     C         3 x_2_3
# 9 y     D         1 y_1_2
#10 y     D         2 y_1_2
#11 y     E         1 y_1_3
#12 y     E         3 y_1_3
#13 y     F         2 y_2_3
#14 y     F         3 y_2_3
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Group Combi Value
x     A     1
x     A     2
x     A     3
x     A     4
x     B     1
x     B     3
x     C     2
x     C     3
y     D     1
y     D     2
y     E     1
y     E     3
y     F     2
y     F     3", header = T)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I often have more than two entries per Group per Combi. I made a remark in the question text now. Is it possible to take care about this in the code. Thank you so much!

Comment: @FeldO If/When you have `>2` entries, what will `Combi2` be? Is it the first and the last `Value`, or do you want to concatenate all `Value`s?

Comment: Sorry for not making this clear. I want to concatenate all "Values" in ascending order.

Comment: @FeldO I've edited my answer; please take a look. This should be what you're after.